# Python Not printing expected output to screen from given thread

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

Could someone explain to me why my code doesn't print the expected output [Thread1 36] from the thread? I am currently using python3.7.0 on a mac OS Catalina 10.15.2

Here is my code:

```
import timeit, _thread


def expmod1(a, n, m):
    return (a**n)%m


# avg_time is a higher order function
# argument is the different variations of the expmod(135, 202, 53) function
def avg_time(thread_name, expmod_function):
    print("Start")
    result = expmod_function(135, 202, 53)
    print(thread_name + " " + str(result), flush=True)
    return result


# analysis of all three functions based on average timecost using a constant function as defined by avg_time
def analysis1():
    try:
        _thread.start_new_thread(avg_time, ("Thread1", expmod1))
    except:
        print("Unable to start thread")


def main():
    analysis1()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What is it currently printing?

Comment: Nothing is currently printing

Comment: When using online python compilers, the code print the expected output whereas when using my default mac compiler nothing is printed. I don't understand why this is the case in mac OS Catalina + python3.7.0. Any ideas??

Comment: Why are you using the private, implementation-dependant ``_thread`` package instead of ``threading``?